# Does time constant or rise time concept apply in transformers as well?

Tags: voltage, transformer, frequency, polarity, rise-time

I am new to electrical engineering.

I have made a transformer where I kept one primary and two secondaries, there's an air gap between the primary leg and secondaries on toroidal core, you can watch that transformer here — https://youtu.be/w4gXINC0Gqg

In that transformer, the back EMF induced flux links to the primary flux despite an air gap between the primary and secondary. That's because the polarity of the fluxes from primary and secondary are opposite, that is, when primary makes north at top, the secondary makes south at top and hence they attract each other despite the air gap between them.

My understanding is, if I raise the frequency to the primary coil, at one frequency the polarity of the primary flux and secondary flux will be opposite and they will repel each other.

Is this time constant (TC = L/R) or rise time concept applicable in transformers as well? If yes, is there a formula to calculate the rise time by voltage, frequency etc?

What happens in a transformer if we keep raising the frequency to the primary?

Comment: A back-emf does not induce anything. A back-emf is created by induction.

Comment: My terminologies are not accurate as i am no electrical engineer, i want to know the effects of raising frequnecy to primary in a transformer.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer in your question. I also think that nobody is going to bother watching your video because it isn't delivering what is needed <-- you need a schematic of your set-up and not a video description of the circuit. EEs need schematics, not words, or videos. You also need to explain why you think you will get repulsion (the opposite of load flux cancellation). But, repulsion is not a term we use when explaining transformers --> flux cancellation or, flux addition.

Comment: _"That's because the polarity of the fluxes from primary and secondary are opposite, that is"_ This does not make sense. Flux in the core is induced by the voltage on the primary. It's not cancelled out by the secondary. Instead, the flux will induce voltage in the secondary.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about perpetual motion.

Comment: Why nobody has understood the question? It's not about perpetual motion, it's simply about the effect of frequency on output and input of transformer and, is time constant or rise time applicable on the polarity of fluxes in transformer just like it does in motors?

Comment: How a transformer behaves with respect to input frequency only really has meaning when you're examining a proper transformer. When the copper/iron thing is supposed to be an over unity machine, you have already left sensible physics behind, and the answers cannot match the questions. Most of the bad jargon you've picked up from the 'design' you're trying to copy is gobbledygook intended to confuse people, because the design cannot physically do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: _"How can I increase amperage at secondary?"_ Load it more.

Comment: You can't just "ask a different important question" after you've gotten answers to your original question. If you have a new question, please post a new one.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The variables involved on transformers development are  voltage, current and frequency, considering ideal conditions, and, in real conditions, losses associated.

Transformers are usually designed to work in a specific frequency or constant properties, because the voltage of a transformer has a proportional relationship with frequency, and the voltage of a transformer at a given flux density increases with frequency and also decreases with it.

So, answering your question, you have the EMF equation:

[image: The EMF force of transformers]

So if frequency increases, the secondary voltage or emf increases. And secondary voltage decreases by the reduction of supply frequency.

But with high frequency there is increase in transformer losses like core loss and conductor skin effect and the magnetizing current becomes low and with low frequency the magnetizing current becomes high.

I recommend you to take a look into the "Fundamentals of Electric Circuits" from Charles K. Alexander & Matthew Sadiku. For introducing electronics is really good, it is easy to find and have an entire chapter about transformers.

Have a noice day!

Comment: *So if frequency increases, the secondary voltage or emf increases* <--- fundamental error in understanding. *But with high frequency there is increase in transformer losses like core loss* <-- given that the dominant core loss is usually saturation loss this statement is also pretty much wrong too.

Comment: _"voltage of a transformer has a proportional relationship with frequency"_ No, it's a max V/f a given transformer can work with without saturating it. As long as you stay below that value, the primary to secondary voltage ratio will stay the same, regardless os frequency (within resonable limits).

Comment: @Andyaka FYI, saturation doesn't incur any loss, in and of itself; core loss is just rather high around those levels, regardless. Eddy current loss may increase (effectively, skin depth is deeper due to reduced average permeability), but that's just called "core loss" all the same.

Answer (score 5):

I had a few minutes spare when I could watch your video.

You complain it's not working. It's working perfectly. When you alter the variable transformer, meters change value, hum levels change, lots of things happening as an engineer would expect.

You appear to be trying to reproduce Thane Hein's bogus over-unity transformer setup. There's a very good reason why that won't work, and that's physics. It's nothing to do with the air-gap, or the wrong polarity of emf repelling the flux (whatever that's supposed to mean). Over unity, aka perpertual motion, doesn't work. Period.

With an efficient transformer setup, you'll lose very little of your input power. With an inefficient setup, you'll lose much more. You and Thane have built the latter.

Unfortunately transformers are more complicated than components like capacitors and resistors, such that a lot of people seem to think they are magic. But if they are magic, what if we could get a few more windings onto a few more branches of core, what might we produce? The possibilities are endless! Unfortunately, all possibilities are limited to a power_out / power_in ratio of less than 100%.

Unfortunately, while you are in pursuit of the fantastical over-unity machine, by reproducing deliberately over-complicated and incorrectly explained equipment, there is little point in talking about the effect of frequency on transformers, or saturation, or polarities of flux. It's all meaningless, as it's out of context.

If you want to learn about transformers, then [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) has quite a reasonable page on them.

There are rational things to do with the over-unity concept. For instance, if you are a craftsman, fashioning a mechanical system that has so little loss that it runs for an extraordinarily long time can be quite fun. An engineer might have fun building what appears to run like a perpetual motion machine, hiding high performance batteries in the framework, or ghosting power from the mains powered 'measuring equipment'. Then there is creative writing, coming up with florid prose designed to confuse otherwise intelligent people about how this over-complicated thing is supposed to work. Finally, there are some people who actually make money with a combination of the above, scamming money out of investors, there are some that fall for it.